# Quickbook Desktop + Magento 2 Integration

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions, integration

I have installed an extension Magenest QuickBooks Desktop Integration in Magento 2 and working fine with Quickbook desktop app.

Extension Synchronise data from Magento 2 to Quickbook Desktop application, But is it possible to fetch or synchronise data from Quickbook Pro desktop app to Magento 2?

Let's say I'm going to create an order from Quickbook Desktop application and that order should sync to Magento 2. So Is it possible in my case?

Comment: You should ask this question from Quickbook Support instead.

Comment: possible using API integration